# Image background change on mousehover event of button in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in WPF. I try to create a menu with button. I set image as background of Button. But image background change on mouse hover event.

My xaml file code,

```
  <Menu x:Name="MainMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Foreground="White" Background="Black" IsTabStop="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Focusable="False" >
            <Button x:Name="Menu_btnAdd" Cursor="Arrow"  ToolTip="Add" Height="100" Width="100" TabIndex="1" IsEnabled="true" IsDefault="True" IsHitTestVisible="true" 
                    Click="Menu_btnAdd_Click"   MouseDown="Menu_btnAdd_MouseDown" >
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Drawings.png">

                    </ImageBrush>
                </Button.OpacityMask>
                <Button.Foreground>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Drawings.png"/>
                </Button.Foreground>
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Drawings.png"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Drawings.png"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="Menu_btnView" Cursor="Arrow"  ToolTip="View" Height="100" Width="100" TabIndex="1" IsEnabled="true" IsDefault="True" 
                    >
                <Button.OpacityMask>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Components.png">

                    </ImageBrush>
                </Button.OpacityMask>
                <Button.Foreground>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Components.png"/>
                </Button.Foreground>
                <Button.BorderBrush>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Components.png"/>
                </Button.BorderBrush>
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Components.png"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
        </Menu>
```

On mouse hover button background result : 
[image]
Please guide me what property I need to set so my background image is not change?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse hover is ***default visual state of Button*** which is getting enabled. To overcome that, you have to ***override default template of button*** and get rid of that.

But, I can suggest a workaround, see if it works for you. Instead of setting Image as background, add it as ***content of a button***.

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="Images/Menu_Drawings.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

---

Other option would be to ***override default template of Button*** and get rid of triggers of mouse hover. *(added sample below after removing those triggers)* Declare template under resources and apply on button which you want to have that look.

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ModifiedTemplate" TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    Name="border"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                                    Name="contentPresenter"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    Focusable="False" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FFBCDDEE</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FF245A83</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FFF4F4F4</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FFADB2B5</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush>#FF838383</SolidColorBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ModifiedTemplate}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Menu_Drawings.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Menu>
```

Comment: First idea is good.Can any option to change the color of mouse hover event while highlight the image on button

Comment: For that to work you need to override default template and provide your own set of brushes like provided in second sample.